# Clean separation of view and code with Vue using templates

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, vue.js

I hope this is a trivial problem for someone and I am just missing a tiny magic piece of code: I am migrating from `knockout.js` to `vue.js` and I am wondering if there is a simple way to use templates the same way in `vue.js` as in `knockout.js`. The following code snipped uses `knockout.js` and works as expected:

```js
function viewmodel() {
    this.person = ko.observable(new person());
}
function person() {
    this.first = ko.observable('hello');
    this.last = ko.observable('world');
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
    <p data-bind="text: first"/>
    <p data-bind="text: last"/>
</script>
<div>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: person }"/>
</div>
```

However, I can't figure out how to achieve the same in `vue.js`. I am aware of components in `vue.js` and all that, but I want to keep the structure as it is and not put more view-specific code into my JavaScript files. (I am already not happy with the `el: '#app'`, but that's my least concern at the moment) Of course this code doesn't work:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        person: {
            first: 'hello',
            last: 'world'
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="person-template">
    <p v-text="first"/>
    <p v-text="last"/>
</script>
<div id="app">
    <div><!-- how? is this even possible? --></div>
</div>
```

**Is there a way to get this working by only changing the HTML part of code?** Preferably only the `<div>`-Element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is not quite *only* changing the template, but a single additional property can work here. Specify a template in the Vue.

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: "#person-template",
    data: {
        person: {
            first: 'hello',
            last: 'world'
        }
    }
});
```

I also modified your template slightly because a template for any Vue or component requires one root element. I recommend you do *not* use self closing tags in Vue as I've seen this cause issues. Vue requires valid HTML5 and [self closing tags are not valid HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/38065).

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="person-template">
  <div>
    <p v-text="person.first"></p>
    <p v-text="person.last"></p>
  </div>
</script>
```

Working [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/gWVXRN).

Additionally, a very common way of specifying templates in this fashion, without using the kind of hacky script tag is to use the HTML5 [template element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

```
<template id="person-template">
  <div>
    <p v-text="person.first"></p>
    <p v-text="person.last"></p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Finally, knowing you are slightly unhappy with the `el:"#app"` You *can* leave the `el` property out of the Vue definition and mount the Vue on an element of your choice using the [$mount](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount) method. So if you wanted to go completely hog wild on separation of concerns you could do something like this.

```
const renderer = Vue.compile(document.querySelector("#person-template").innerHTML)
const example = {
    data: {
        person: {
            first: 'hello',
            last: 'world'
        }
    }
}
const app = new Vue(Object.assign({}, example, renderer))
app.$mount("#app")
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/wdVPEM?editors=1010).

I should mention nobody really does that (compiling their templates manually, it's common to use $mount) that I'm aware of. It also depends on using the version of Vue that includes the compiler (which you might not have if you are using webpack or some other build tool for example). You could also do something like this:

```
const app = new Vue(Object.assign({}, example, {template: "#person-template"}))
app.$mount("#app")
```

which would basically allow you to specify a template, a component, and a place to mount it [all separately](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/xdvpxm?editors=1010).

Comment: @NumLock so, I had a few more ideas and added them after you accepted the answer. Just FYI.

Comment: Thanks. I _really_ appreciate all the effort. I am currently trying to grasp the implications about directly referencing `person` inside the template instead of just its properties. With my KO example I could just reuse the template for basically everything that has those two properties. As it is now (from my current understanding at least) I just offloaded how to render person instead of defining a (reusable) template

Comment: @NumLock You can always define a person component that just renders the person.

Comment: There is a user here, @RoyJ, that answers quite a few Vue and Knockout questions. You also might want to ping him with any questions transitioning from Knockout to Vue.